# Разность односвязных списков

Tags: c++, списки, односвязный-список

```
#include "stdafx.h"
using namespace std;


struct list
{
    int val;
    list *next;
};

void print(list *a)
{
    list *p = a;
    cout << "Spisok: ";
    while (p != NULL)
    {
        cout << p->val;
        p = p->next;
    }
}

list *init(int a)
{
    list *head = new list;
    head->val = a;
    head->next = NULL;
    return (head);
}

list *add(list *head, int data)
{
    list *temp, *p;
    p = head->next;
    temp = new list;
    head->next = temp;
    temp->val = data;
    temp->next = p;
    return (temp);
}

void del(list *&p, int v)
{
    if (p == NULL)
        return;
    list *t = p;
    if (t->val == v)
    {
        p = t->next;
        delete t;
        return;
    }

    list *t1 = t->next;
    while (t1)
    {
        if (t1->val == v)
        {
            t->next = t1->next;
            delete t1;
            return;
        }
        t = t1;
        t1 = t1->next;
    }
}

void sub(list *&a, list *&b)
{
    list *p1, *p2;
    p1 = a;
    p2 = b;
    while (p1)
    {
        while (p2)
        {
            if (p1->val == p2->val)
                del(p1, p1->val);
            p2 = p2->next;
        }
        p1 = p1->next;
    }
}


int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");

    list *p1 = new list;
    list *p2 = new list;
    p1 = init(5);
    add(p1, 6);
    add(p1, 9);
    p2 = init(6);
    add(p2, 7);

    sub(p1, p2);
    print(p1);
    cout << endl;
    print(p2);

    delete p1;
    delete p2;
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Не работает функция разности списков sub. Не могу понять в чем ошибка.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести и т. д.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод `sub` полностью неверен.

Смотрите, что вы делаете. На первой итерации внешнего цикла вы сравниваете все элементы второго списка с головным элементом первого. Затем вы не реинициализируете `p2`, и в дальнейших итерациях он остаётся равным `NULL`. Таким образом, дальнейшие итерации вовсе ничего не делают.

Смотрите, что надо сделать. Обратите внимание на то, что метод `del` удаляет значение во *всём* списке. Поэтому вам должно быть достаточно пробежаться по второму списку, и вызвать `del` для каждого элемента второго списка:

```
for (list *p2 = b; p2; p2 = p2->next)
    del(a, p2->val);
```

или оставаясь в стиле вашего кода

```
list *p2;
p2 = b;
while (p2)
{
    del(a, p2->val);
    p2 = p2->next;
}
```

Обратите внимание, что вам нужно удалять по `a`, а не его копии `p1`, потому что процедура `del` может модифицировать переданный указатель.

В коде ещё наверняка есть погрешности. Например, у вас потеря памяти в начале `main` (`list *p1 = new list;` — это значение тут же теряется). (И в конце: для освообждения памяти списка простого `delete` недостаточно.)